# flex card should be nested with space between each other, How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

The other 2 have no background for some reason

```css
h1 {
  text-align: justify;
}

.flexcard {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.flexcard1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 52px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.userbio {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcard">
  <div class="flexcard1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1" alt="">
    <h1>FlexCard</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="userBio">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores. Cumque quis esse nihil architecto
      in, nulla quia, facere, numquam id quos mollitia. <br> Est beatae vero qui voluptatibus sed, alias a delectus harum sapiente quasi id aliquid ipsum ullam dolore reprehenderit asperiores dolorum atque quis maxime repudiandae exercitationem quia accusantium
      debitis? At fugit atque deserunt numquam est necessitatibus, tempora quae laboriosam aliquam ullam accusamus vitae laborum praesentium delectus maxime soluta. Nam corporis illum, tempora explicabo autem libero deserunt alias aliquid?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcard1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2" alt="">
    <h1>FlexCard</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="userBio">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores. Cumque quis esse nihil architecto
      in, nulla quia, facere, numquam id quos mollitia. <br> Est beatae vero qui voluptatibus sed, alias a delectus harum sapiente quasi id aliquid ipsum ullam dolore reprehenderit asperiores dolorum atque quis maxime repudiandae exercitationem quia accusantium
      debitis? At fugit atque deserunt numquam est necessitatibus, tempora quae laboriosam aliquam ullam accusamus vitae laborum praesentium delectus maxime soluta. Nam corporis illum, tempora explicabo autem libero deserunt alias aliquid?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcard1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="">
    <h1>FlexCard</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="userBio">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores. Cumque quis esse nihil architecto
      in, nulla quia, facere, numquam id quos mollitia. <br> Est beatae vero qui voluptatibus sed, alias a delectus harum sapiente quasi id aliquid ipsum ullam dolore reprehenderit asperiores dolorum atque quis maxime repudiandae exercitationem quia accusantium
      debitis? At fugit atque deserunt numquam est necessitatibus, tempora quae laboriosam aliquam ullam accusamus vitae laborum praesentium delectus maxime soluta. Nam corporis illum, tempora explicabo autem libero deserunt alias aliquid?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet out of your code

Comment: ty appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <div class="flexcard">
    <div class="flexcard-col">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/" alt="">
      <h1>FlexCard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flexcard-col">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
 body{
    height: 100%;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: bisque;
 }
.flexcard {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: pink;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
.flexcard-col{
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.flexcard-col img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
.flexcard-col:last-child {
   text-align: justify;
   text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sb621hv7/)

Answer (score 0):

This is more what you like?

The changes:

- I restructured the HTML code. It's not

  > - flexcard
  >
  >   - flexcard1
  >   - userbio
  >   - flexcard1
  >   - userbio
  >   - flexcard1
  >   - userbio

  anymore, but

  > - flexcard
  >
  >   - flexcard1
  >
  >     - userInfo *
  >     - userbio
  >   - flexcard1
  >
  >     - userInfo *
  >     - userbio
  >   - flexcard1
  >
  >     - userInfo *
  >     - userbio

  **) New by me*
- I removed the width value from `.flexcard`
- I moved the background properties from `.flexcard` to `.flexcard1`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: bisque;
}

h1 {
  text-align: justify;
}

.flexcard {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  /*width: 350px;*/
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
}

.flexcard1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 52px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
  display: flex;
}

.userbio {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcard">
  <div class="flexcard1">
    <div class="userInfo">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1" alt="">
      <h1>FlexCard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="userBio">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores. Cumque quis esse nihil architecto
        in, nulla quia, facere, numquam id quos mollitia. <br> Est beatae vero qui voluptatibus sed, alias a delectus harum sapiente quasi id aliquid ipsum ullam dolore reprehenderit asperiores dolorum atque quis maxime repudiandae exercitationem quia
        accusantium debitis? At fugit atque deserunt numquam est necessitatibus, tempora quae laboriosam aliquam ullam accusamus vitae laborum praesentium delectus maxime soluta. Nam corporis illum, tempora explicabo autem libero deserunt alias aliquid?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcard1">
    <div class="userInfo">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2" alt="">
      <h1>FlexCard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="userBio">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores. Cumque quis esse nihil architecto
        in, nulla quia, facere, numquam id quos mollitia. <br> Est beatae vero qui voluptatibus sed, alias a delectus harum sapiente quasi id aliquid ipsum ullam dolore reprehenderit asperiores dolorum atque quis maxime repudiandae exercitationem quia
        accusantium debitis? At fugit atque deserunt numquam est necessitatibus, tempora quae laboriosam aliquam ullam accusamus vitae laborum praesentium delectus maxime soluta. Nam corporis illum, tempora explicabo autem libero deserunt alias aliquid?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcard1">
    <div class="userInfo">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="">
      <h1>FlexCard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="userBio">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt facilis unde voluptate blanditiis nam quae nulla eaque et quisquam, repellendus dolores at culpa pariatur optio dolorum! Laborum sit neque asperiores. Cumque quis esse nihil architecto
        in, nulla quia, facere, numquam id quos mollitia. <br> Est beatae vero qui voluptatibus sed, alias a delectus harum sapiente quasi id aliquid ipsum ullam dolore reprehenderit asperiores dolorum atque quis maxime repudiandae exercitationem quia
        accusantium debitis? At fugit atque deserunt numquam est necessitatibus, tempora quae laboriosam aliquam ullam accusamus vitae laborum praesentium delectus maxime soluta. Nam corporis illum, tempora explicabo autem libero deserunt alias aliquid?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added description to my answer

Comment: @LaidBack Please accept the answer (gray tick mark on the left), if it is the answer you were looking for. You will receive 2 reputation and I'll receive 15 reputation